# Como fazer um crud com Json usando PHP

Tags: php, html, json, laravel, crud

Eu estou começando uns estudos emm php e quero conseguir fazer um crud usando um json. Eu ja consegui criar o arquivo e escrever nele, ja consigo tambem ler os dados. Mas estou tendo um problema. Na primeira vez, em que gero o arquivo e jogo os dados nele vazio, funciona de boa, mas na segunda vez, o arquivo ja me trás um estrutura errada do arquivo json. Como eu posso consertar isso?

Meu código:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

    $dados_preenchidos = array(
        'codigo'   => rand(1000, 9999)."",
        'nome'     => $nome,
        'email'    => $email,
        'telefone' => $telefone
    );

    $dados = array($dados_preenchidos);
    $dados_json = json_encode($dados);
    $fp = fopen("bd/dados.json", "a");
    $escreve = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);
    fclose($fp);

    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

**Sore o JSON:**

Na primeria vez, ele cria e gera os dados assim:

> [{"codigo":"3709","nome":"samuel","email":"email@gmail.com","telefone":"123456789"}]

Beleza, esta correto e aparece na tela pra mim certinho, mas quando insiro um segundo registro, ele fica assim:

> [{"codigo":"3709","nome":"teste1","email":"email@gmail.com","telefone":"1234567897"}][{"codigo":"8718","nome":"teste2","email":"email2@gmail.com","telefone":"789456123"}]

Repare que o "[" se repete, quando deveria ser assim:

> [{"codigo":"3709","nome":"teste1","email":"email@gmail.com","telefone":"1234567897"},{"codigo":"8718","nome":"teste2","email":"email2@gmail.com","telefone":"789456123"}]

Fiz o teste alterando a mão pra forma correta e o código funcionou perfeitamente...

Como eu faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra possibilidade é a seguinte:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

    $dados_preenchidos = array(
        'codigo' => rand(1000, 9999) . "",
        'nome' => $nome,
        'email' => $email,
        'telefone' => $telefone
    );

    $dados_preenchidos = array($dados_preenchidos);
    $dados_recuperados = array();

    //Verifica se um arquivo existe
    if (file_exists("bd/dados.json")) {

        //Lê o conteúdo do arquivo e retona em uma string
        $content = file_get_contents("bd/dados.json");
        if ($content) {
            //Decodifica uma string JSON, passando o parametro true o object retornado será convertido em array associativo.
            $arrayContent = json_decode($content, true);
            foreach ($arrayContent as $valor) {
                //Adiciona o array valor no final do array dados recuperados
                array_push($dados_recuperados, $valor);
            }
        }
    }

    //combina os arrays
    $dados_merge = array_merge($dados_preenchidos, $dados_recuperados);
    $dados_json = json_encode($dados_merge);

    $fp = fopen("bd/dados.json", "w");
    $escreve = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);
    fclose($fp);

    header('Location: index.php');
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, SaMuk você pode trabalhar da seguinte maneira (comentei o código para ficar fácil o entendimento):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

    // Atribui o conteúdo do arquivo para variável $arquivo
    $arquivo = file_get_contents('bd/dados.json');

    // Decodifica o formato JSON e retorna um Objeto
    $dados_preenchidos = json_decode($arquivo);

    //acrescenta a informação que precisa no Objeto
    $dados_preenchidos[] = array(
        'codigo'   => rand(1000, 9999)."",
        'nome'     => $nome,
        'email'    => $email,
        'telefone' => $telefone
    );

//codifica em json
$dados_json = json_encode($dados_preenchidos);

//salva o arquivo
    file_put_contents("bd/dados.json",$dados_json);
}
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Leandro, obrigado pela resposta, mas deu um erro no seu código, na linha `$dados_json = json_encode($dados_preenchidos);`, o erro é este: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$dados_json' (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: corrigi. Faltou um ; na linha acima; Pode testar

Comment: cara. ainda sim nao funcionou, de erro nessa linha agora: `$arquivo = file_get_contents('dados.json');`

Comment: bd/dados.json
Vou alterar a resposta

Comment: eu vi isso, e ja tentei alterar tambem, mas continuou com o erro kkk